# Rounding to 1 decimal place in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I need help in figuring out on how I can output a number with 1 decimal place.
Here is the line of code I'm currently using:

```
(cast(round((p.NewHouseHoldsEnrolled + p.ContinuingHouseholds),1) as numeric(38,0)) /p.MaximumServiceCapacity) * 100 as  'Capacity Percentage'
```

An example number I get from using this is 67.500000
but I need 67.5

I am also using BigInts

Answer (score 0):

You need an outer cast to do it the way you are currently.

```
cast((cast(round((p.NewHouseHoldsEnrolled + p.ContinuingHouseholds),1) as numeric(38,0)) /p.MaximumServiceCapacity) * 100) as numeric(38,1) as  'Capacity Percentage'
```

Alternatively, you could clean it up like so

```
cast(round((p.NewHouseHoldsEnrolled + p.ContinuingHouseholds),1) / p.MaximumServiceCapacity * 100 as numeric(38, 1)) as  'Capacity Percentage'
```

Review [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) for more information on scale and presicion.

Comment: do you know how to round to the nearest 1st decimal? Because now i'm resulting in 67.0 and not 67.5

Comment: nvm I got it! Had to multiply by 100.0 and not 100. Thank you!